# Merge rows in table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My table consists of availability status data for each day of the month where a row represents a given month and each column is a day.  I stores statuses like 'Available', 'Unavailable', etc.

This works great until I want to display data by week.  The issue I run into is when I get to a week that crosses into the next month.  Right now I'm using a query that looks like:

```
$query = "SELECT pilots.id AS pid, "
       . "pilots.last_name AS last_name, "
       . "pilots.first_name AS first_name, "
       . "rt.* FROM pilots "
       . "LEFT JOIN ("
       . "SELECT * FROM availability "
       . "WHERE date ='"  
       . $first_date_of_month->format("Y-m-d") 
       . $next_month_str . "')rt "
       . "ON pilots.id = rt.pilot_id "
       . "ORDER BY pilots.last_name, pilots.first_name, pid";
```

Which looks like:

```
SELECT p.id pid
     , p.last_name
     , p.first_name
     , rt.* 
  FROM pilots p
  LEFT 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT * 
         FROM availability 
        WHERE date ='2017-06-01' 
         OR date = '2017-07-01'
     )rt 
    ON p.id = rt.pilot_id 
 ORDER 
    BY p.last_name
     , p.first_name
     , pid
```

The problem with this is let's say I have 1 user and 2 months of data.  It returns 2 rows.  I really only want 1 row where the data is merged using columns from the end of one month and beginning of another month.

For example:

```
//Pilots
-------------------------
| id|first_name|last_name|
-------------------------
| 1 | "myTest" |"myTest" |
-------------------------

// Months
----------------------------------------------------------------------
| id|pilot_id|  date  |   1_status  |   2_status  |....|  30_status  |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------|
| 1 |   1    |3/1/2017| "Available" |"Unavailable"|....| "Available" |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------|
| 2 |   1    |4/1/2017|"Unavailable"|"Unavailable"|....|"Unavailable"|
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

In the first example (not within 7 days of the end of the month), it's simple: I will have 1 record because I know I do not need the next month.  Let's say it's "3/21/2017"; I just output the statuses for "3/21/2017", "3/22/2017", and so on.

However, let's say the week I want to display starts at "3/28/2017".  I need the data from March and for April.  In this case, it generates 2 rows of data for pilot_id 1.  But I really only need 28_status, 29_status, 30_status, 31_status, and THEN need 1_status, 2_status (all from April).

Attached $next_month_str below:

```
            $next_month_str = "";
            if (!is_last_day_of_month($sunday_date))
            {
                $next_month = get_next_month($monday_date);
                $next_month_str = "' OR date = '";
                $next_month_str = $next_month_str . $next_month->format("Y-m-d");
                $next_month_str = $next_month_str;
            }

$query_inner = "SELECT pilot_id, 26_status, 27_status, 28_status, 29_status, 30_status FROM availability WHERE date = '2017-06-01'";
$query = "SELECT availability.pilot_id AS pid, rt.26_status, rt.27_status, rt.28_status, rt.29_status, rt.30_status, availability.1_status, availability.2_status FROM availability INNER JOIN (" . $query_inner . ")rt ON rt.pilot_id = pid WHERE date = '2017-07-01'";
```

There are two queries I came up with.  Separate they work fine, and they work fine when I test them out using a SQL checker and they do exactly what I want.  However, when I run it in my site, they give me a error querying the database.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  That would be a much better explanation of what you want to accomplish.

Comment: I am unsure what the purpose `$next_month_str` is in your SQL statement I attempted to rewrite it to make it more readable but confused.

Comment: Usually these things are difficult because the design isn't right. Do as Gordon asks and we may be able to help you with both.

Comment: See corrections.

Comment: @MichaelNiño, it was used in an 'if' statement to decid if I want to get 1 month or 2 months of data by using the date.  For example "WHERE date = '2017-06-01' OR date = '2017-07-01'".  It was the part of the string that was either null or included "OR date = '2017-07-01'"

Comment: I agree with @twoleggedhorse your query will depend on a good set of related tables. In short, you'll need to use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` to return the result set you are describing.

Comment: Your months table is horrendous. Rethink the design of that table, or forget about using an RDBMS

Comment: @Strawberry, care to help?

Comment: Ok well, a normalised availability table might look like this: `pilot_id,date,status` - although one could assume that a pilot was unavailable unless otherwise stated.

Comment: @Strawberry, funny you should say that.  After spending more time, I ended up going with that design because even though I solved this issued I ran into others.  Refactoring is a good thing! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

I can build the query string programatically, but using JOINs I was able to solve it.  Does exactly what I want it to.  Here is an example of a string:

```
SELECT availability.pilot_id, rt.26_status, rt.27_status, rt.28_status, rt.29_status, rt.30_status, availability.1_status, availability.2_status FROM availability INNER JOIN (SELECT pilot_id, 26_status, 27_status, 28_status, 29_status, 30_status FROM availability WHERE date = '2017-06-01')rt ON rt.pilot_id = availability.pilot_id WHERE date = '2017-07-01'
```

EDIT:  Although I was able to solve the question using this, ultimately it was a design issue that forced this.  I decided to refactor and use a table like availability {id, pilot_id, date, status}.

Comment: id would appear to serve no purpose here. `(pilot_id,date)` must be UNIQUE, rendering the surrogate redundant.

Comment: @Strawberry, further improved.  Guess I should have taken that DB design class in college that I decided to skip.  Thanks!

Comment: You didn't miss much

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, you need to use `GROUP BY`, `HAVING` and possibly `GROUP_CONCAT()` to essentially "flatten" your results set. Here are some resources so you may learn how and then apply that knowledge.

- [GROUP_CONCAT()](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php)
- [GROUP BY, HAVING](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-having.aspx)

The above resources have a sandbox for you try play around with the SQL statements.

Comment: Added it to my question.  Please see above.

Comment: I have updated my answer to provide the resources you need to accomplish what you are seeking.

Comment: What about multiple JOINs?

Comment: You might benefit greatly from a book on SQL. I would recommend getting a subscription at SafariBooksOnline.com

Comment: valid.  Weird issue... so I used a SQL checker to run the 2 last queries in the code about and they work exactly how I want them to.  However, when I run them in my app I get a error querying the database.  Looks valid to me.